# Angular put request is hitting null value

Tags: angular8, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a webapi to fetch Bank Account details, when i try to test it using postman it works fine, but while trying to access put method from my angular client, i am getting following error.

This is the **Error**

```
PUT https://localhost:44332/api/bankaccount/null 400
errors:
id: ["The value 'null' is not valid."]
$.bankAccountID: [""The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.bankAccountID | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 21."]
```

It is evident from error that, i am getting null value instead of Integer. I am not able to figure out why it is hitting null value, Could you help me with this. I am using Asp.net Core 3.0 with Angular 8

form code in component.html

```
 <form class="tr" [formGroup]="fg" *ngFor="let fg of bankAccountForm.controls" (submit)="recordSubmit(fg)">

            <div class="td">
                <input class="form-control" formControlName="accountNumber" >
            </div>

            <div class="td">
                <input class="form-control" formControlName="accountHolder" >
            </div>

            <div class="td">
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="bankID" >
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let item of bankList" [ngValue]="item.bankID">{{
                        item.bankName
                      }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="td">
                <input class="form-control" formControlName="IFSC" >
            </div>

            <div class="td">
               <button type="submit" class="btn" [ngClass]="(fg.get('bankAccountID').value==0?'btn-success':'btn-outline-dark')" 
               [disabled]="fg.invalid"><i class="far fa-save fa-lg"></i> 
                   {{fg.get('bankAccountID').value==0?'Submit':'Update'}}</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

component.ts form creation

```
  addBankAccountForm(){
    this.bankAccountForm.push(this.fb.group({
      bankAccountID:[0],
      accountNumber:['', Validators.required],
      accountHolder:['', Validators.required],
      bankID:[0, Validators.min(1)],
      IFSC:['']
    }));
  }
```

Save Method in component.ts file

```
    if(fg.value.bankAccountID==0)
    {
      this.service.postBankAccount(fg.value).subscribe(
        (res:any) =>{

          fg.patchValue({bankAccountID:res.bankAccountID});
        });
      }
        else{
    // here if i try to console fg.value i get bankAccountID as null 
          this.service.putBankAccount(fg.value).subscribe(
            (res:any) =>{

            });

        }

  }
```

Put method in service.ts class

```
  putBankAccount(formData){
    return this.http.put(environment.apiBaseURI + '/bankaccount/'+ formData.bankAccountID, formData);

  }
```

WebApi Model class

```
public class BankAccount
    {
        public int BankAccountId { get; set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string AccountHolder { get; set; }
        public int BankID { get; set; }
        public string IFSC { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller put method

```
 // PUT: api/Banks/5

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutBank(int id, Bank bank)
        {
            if (id != bank.BankID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(bank).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BankExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the “[FromRoute]” attribute to the “id” parameter in your api? Also, I STRONGLY suggest always using the “===“ operator as opposed to the “==“ operator in JavaScript/TypeScript

Comment: It didnt make any difference with [FormRoute] , the value is still null . I am sure there is no problem with Api, as i can use postman to update it . The problem is, at the time of put request from client side it is not getting ID value, it is getting it as null

Comment: I've added the same code into another angular project and everything works out okay for me (i.e. not getting null). Is there something else you haven't posted that could be manipulating the value?

Comment: The problem was in casing , i solved it by debugging my code.I found that when i try to access `fg.patchValue({bankAccountID:res.bankAccountID});` the patch value it self was null , i just changed the casing of `bankAccountID to bankAccountId` and everything worked fine